# How to add lagging Features for Forecasting with a random lag range without adding a new column per lag?

Tags: feature-engineering, forecasting, feature-construction, generalization

The common way of adding lagging features in time series forecasting problems is adding lag columns with pandas.shift(). While it is a fine method but what about when wanting to use a random integer (within a range) for lags per observation without adding a new column per lag?

Answer (score 0):

###### Creating the DataFrame

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})

###### Applying different random shift for each observation in y.

number_of_lags        = 10

df['lag_shift_value'] = [random.randint(1, number_of_lags ) for _ in range(len(df))]

###### Shifting y for each observation based on these random values

df['y_lag_random'] = [df['y'].shift(df['lag_shift_value'][i]).iloc[i] for i in range(len(df))]

- result Dataframe shape:
  col1 : x
  col2 : lag_shift_value
  col3 : y_lag_random
  col4 : y
- dataframe will have same number of rows.
- Below is an example of error analysis of number of lags (x-axis) and error distribution of future predictions (y-axis).
- A linear/non-linear model trained this way might have more robustness.

[image]